# Qt5.5 Scripting

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I am using Qt5.5, I need a way to evalulate an expression.  I would like to use the QScriptEngine, but cannot find a full and complete example on how to use it.

I've tried including:

```
    #include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>
```

However, after building I get:

```
    undefined reference to `QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()'
    undefined reference to `QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()'
    undefined reference to `QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[edit]...Thank you @OMGtechy, changed include to:

```
    #include <QJSEngine>
```

And:

```
   QJSEngine engine;
```

No more issue.

Comment: Qt Script is deprecated, prefer QJSEngine instead (although this isn't your problem).

Also, make sure you have the correct Qt libraries specified in your .pro file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced references to QtScript header with QJSEngine as suggested by OMGtechy, no more issue.